# PHP Image Magick Generates a corrupted image after converting SVG to PNG

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png

I have an app that generates svg and then converts that svg to png image. This works on the local virtual host with ubuntu os but when I am trying to make it work on my windows xampp it generates a corrupted file.

My code:

```
$svg = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$svg->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

$svg = $svg->asXML();

if(!file_exists(TMP_DIRECTORY)) {
     mkdir(TMP_DIRECTORY, 0775);
}

$filePath = TMP_DIRECTORY . DS . base64_encode(time()) . ".svg";
file_put_contents($filePath, $svg);

$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);

$im = new Imagick();

$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

$im->setFont("C:/xampp56/htdocs/daimler/fonts/DaimlerCS/DaimlerCS-Demi.otf");

try {
    if (!$im->readImageBlob($contents)) {
                echo 'Cannot read svg file!';
     }
} catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
     exit;
}

$im->setImageFormat("png24");
$filename = TMP_DIRECTORY . DS . 'test.png';
$im->writeImage($filename);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

expected result(generated in virtual host ubuntu os):
[image]

Actual Result in windows xampp server: 
[image]

I hope someone can help me point out where the problem is because there are no error messages shown.

I followed the instructions on this site and installed image magick: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

I have installed the version of image magick defined in the phpinfo imagick class description

[image]

Comment: You may be using two different SVG renderers via Imagemagick. Imagemagick can use its own internal MSVG/XML, RSVG delegate or Inkscape, in order of increasing quality. See which of the former two are being use via `convert -list format` and look at the end of the line for SVG. If Inkscape is installed on the system, Imagemagick will use it in place of the other two. Also check your versions and dates of the versions of Imagemagick and also RSVG if using that.

Comment: Hi @fmw42 Thanks for the answer. Can you recommend me a good link where I can follow to set this up correctly for Windows 10 xampp server?

Comment: This is the result of the command: 
SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.12)

Comment: I know nothing about Windows or Xampp, sorry. Your RSVG  2.40.12 delegate is old. You might try upgrading. Or better, just install Inkscape. That usually is a better SVG Renderer and Imagemagick will use it even if you have RSVG installed. If you post your SVG file, then we can try to test it against all the various renderers and let you know which is best.